# JSON property not deserializing from a different name in Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore, jackson

Here is my POJO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.cloud.Timestamp;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Course {

    private String code;

    private int credits;

    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("last_updated")
    private Timestamp lastUpdated;

    private String name;

    private String prerequisites;

    private String restrictions;

    private Seats seats;

    private Seats waitlist;
}
```

where I am reading data from Firestore which is being implicitly mapped to this class.

The notable difference is that `last_updated` has an underscore in Firestore:

[image]

but I want the JSON to deserialize to just `lastUpdated` without the underscore. I thought that was the point of `@JsonProperty` but all that is happening here is I am getting a null value back:

[image]

and the following logging in Spring Boot:

```sh
2020-06-18 03:44:36.852  WARN 5200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for last_updated found on class ....dto.Course
2020-06-18 03:44:36.852  WARN 5200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for last_updated found on class ....dto.Course
2020-06-18 03:44:36.853  WARN 5200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.g.cloud.firestore.CustomClassMapper    : No setter/field for last_updated found on class ....dto.Course
```

I've debugged it and have confirmed that within the world of Java, `lastUpdated` is always null.

How can I get my POJO to deserialize `last_updated` into the `lastUpdated` POJO field without having to rename the POJO property to `last_updated` (which works, but breaks a lot of linting principles)?

Answer (score 0):

you can get by writing your property like this

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private Date createdDate;
```

`Date` is a fine field type for this. You can make the JSON parse-able pretty easily by using `ObjectMapper.setDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a z");
myObjectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
```

Comment: this doesn't change the error messages or anything at all, sorry